# Org-mode table recalculation with a remote() formula using calc?

Tags: org-table, remote

Can I make table2 automatically recalculate a remote() formula when I modify data in table1?

I have the below tables and the first table is automatically recalculated when I press TAB (thanks to the "#" in the first column), but the second one it's only recalculated when move my cursor over it and press TAB in there as well.

I would like to have it recalculated when I change (TAB) the first table.

```
#+NAME: table1
| # | + Units | value | value2 |
|---+---------+-------+--------|
| # | unit1   |  3110 |    295 |
| # | unit2   |       |        |
| # | unit3   |       |        |
|---+---------+-------+--------|
| # | - Units | value | value2 |
|---+---------+-------+--------|
| # | unit1   |   -40 |        |
| # | unit2   |  -105 |        |
| # | unit3   |   -26 |        |
|---+---------+-------+--------|
| * | TOTAL:  |  2939 |    295 |
|---+---------+-------+--------|
#+TBLFM: @9$3=vsum(@-1..@1);EN::@9$4=vsum(@-1..@1);EN

#+NAME: table2
| # | TOTAL + |  3405 |
| # | TOTAL - |  -171 |   
#+TBLFM: @1$3=vsum(remote(table1,@I$3..@II$3))+vsum(remote(table1,@I$4..@II$4));EN::@2$3=vsum(remote(table1,@III$3..@IIII$3))+vsum(remote(table1,@III$4..@IIII$4));EN
```

I am aware that it might be possible using elisp code but would like to have it work with calc syntax, if possible.

Comment: Welcome! Does `M-x org-table-recalculate-buffer-tables RET` recalculate both tables?

Comment: Yes, it does...

Comment: I have used this command and bind it to <tab> alongside with org-cycle. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you for posting the answer to your question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct solution, or if I'll have trouble when the file gets  bigger, with more tables, but it seems to work for the moment.

Solution: I have used a lambda function to bind both "org-cycle" and "org-table-recalculate-buffer-tables" to key  and both tables are recalculated when I press it.

```
(add-hook 'org-mode-hook
      (lambda()
(local-set-key (kbd "<tab>") (lambda () (interactive) (org-cycle) (org-table-recalculate-buffer-tables)))))
```

Comment: Yes, but ... you have now tied two different functions to the same key with no way of disentangling them. Now pressing TAB *anywhere* in the file (including when you are not in a table) will recalculate every table in the file. It would be better if you bound `org-table-recalculate-buffer-tables` to a different key (e.g. `C-c z` which is usually free) and leave TAB alone.